# Filter out script tags in a view but leave link (from user input)

Tags: views, input-formats

Users of my site will enter their twitter widget code into a field for their profile:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/ussername" data-widget-id="400306334257818144">Tweets by @username</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

In a view I need to display the link exactly how it was entered, but not display anything in the script tags.

Ive tried making the node field both plain text and filtered html (which allows links). Ive also tried the default view and with 'Strip HTML tags' selected but `<a>` allowed. In every instance the link prints out as I want it to. The script tags however are removed but the content is printed as plain text (see below).

```
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

How can I stop this from showing?

Comment: I find the formatting of the code (2x) in this question hard to read. Can you think of reformatting it a bit so that you don't have to do all that scrolling right? FYI: that "might" be part of the reasons of the 2 downvotes, and after you did such edit, those downvoters "might" want to undo their downvotes ... Just a suggestion ... Pls add an extra comment to "ping" me after you eventually did so, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you can use https://drupal.org/project/views_php to add a custom PHP code, where you can manipulate on the data that user has added.

If you are saving this field somewhere and is available as a field in views too, add the field, and select "exclude from display" option. Now, add a custom php code field and take the input from the field above, extract URL from it and return the same.